# Acessing property of javascript object from closure

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have an object like this

```
var graphLUT = {
table: [],
    createEmptyGraph: function (label) {

    var existsInTable = false;
    if(this.table.length > 0) {
        for(var i=0; i<this.table.length; i++) {
            if(this.table[i] === label) existsInTable = true;
            else existsInTable = false;
        }
    }
    else 
        existsInTable = false; 
    if(!existsInTable) {
        var graph = new Graph(label.toLowerCase());
        this.table.push(graph.label); 
        return graph;   
    }  
},
... other properties
};

module.exports = graphLUT
```

When I now try to acces the table from the createEmptyGraph function, the node.js compiler tells me the following:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

What am I doing wrong? I also required the graphLUT and can access the table array from another module so it has the be initialized. Maybe the "this" is wrong? 
How do I access table?

Comment: AFAICS; Your "this" is pointing to "createEmptyGraph" at the time of usage, which does not have a "table" property.

Comment: @MarvinSmit It shouldn't. The problem is probably elsewhere. OP, how exactly are you calling the function ? It looks like you're not calling it on the module (ie as `myModule.createEmptyGraph();`). Are you passing it as a callback to some event handler ?

Comment: `this` example (pun intended) shows why `this` should be avoided. Don't forget you can specify the value it has at call time by using `apply` or `call`

Comment: The issue is not inside the code, but with how you call it. It should be something like `module.exports.createEmptyGraph('MyLabel')`.

Comment: @MarvinSmit in the above example `this` should be refer to the instance of `graphLUT`, this snippet clearly isn't the full story, include an example whereby this issue is occurring.

Comment: @JaredSmith: Or you, you know, properly learn how `this` works.

Comment: OP, your deleted answer would be OK if you just added the wrong calling code in the question and the right calling code in the answer.